# What are the references to the known myths in the movie "The killing of a sacred deer"?

Tags: the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer

The movie is full of references to Greek myths apparently. The title itself, the four stages of sickness, etc. What are the other references that you could name and what known myths do they refer to?

Comment: So people don't get confused, it might be better to ask for allegories or references, because sometimes "myhtology" can relate to the work's actual inverse mythology, as opposed to a reference to "known" myths.

Answer (score 4):

*Killing of a Sacred Deer* is loosely based on Greek myths recorded in plays from Homer, Aeschylus, and Euripides, and seems to be based on the myth of King Agamemnon murdering his daughter, Iphigenia.

This [Vulture piece](http://www.vulture.com/2017/10/the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer-and-greek-myths.html) gives a good run-down of them.

This quote from the article explains where the film’s title comes from.

> However, in Euripides’s *Iphigenia at Aulis*, the reason for
>   Iphigenia’s sacrifice is made more
>   explicit: Agamemnon accidentally killed a sacred deer that belonged to
>   [Artemis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis?wprov=sfti1), and she requires blood in return.

(BTW: If you have questions about the myths, best ask them in the Mythology/Folklore exchange.)

Comment: Providing a summary or quotations from the article would improve this answer markedly.

Comment: I added a quote from the article, but it’s not really something that’s easy to summarise.